# JS Namespace and Backbone to JSON

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, namespaces

I'm building a one page application with Backbone.js. I introduced a namespace and created a module definition like the following:

```
// Declare namespace
var app = app || {};

// Recommendation Model Definition
// -------------------------------
app.Recommendation = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var rec =  new app.Recommendation({id: "1", rating: "2"});
console.log(rec.toJSON());

// Chrome JS console output 
Array[1]
 0: Object
 id: "1"
 rating: "2"
 __proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

The problem is that the toJSON() Method is not returning the direct JSON string but nested in an array. If I'm leaving the namespace out it is doing the right thing. I could obviously just state rec.toJSON()[0] but that doesn't seem to be fine coding ;)?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you certain that you're not looking at a collection? http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8AwYT/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing something wrong... possibly using the Backbone.Collection instead of model... see this:

http://jsfiddle.net/VVLhZ/2/
`$("#output").html(JSON.stringify(rec.toJSON()));`

It shows what you describe does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

here is the doc:
http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON(http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON)

just use `JSON.stringify(rec)`